# How long does it take to finish xfs_repair?

Tags: disk, xfs

If my H.D.D. is almost 2TB, how long should it take to finish it?

Comment: Run in in verbose mode (xfs_repair -v) so you can see what is happening. The time it takes large depends on how full the disk is and is the superblock can be found. The worst time I could find was 12Tb running for 3 days but that was cancelled since the system was irrecoverable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one can tell. It depends on many factors like drive speed, file system usage, the severity of the damage and such things.